# DirectX 11.1 trying to create device to not trigger Timeout Detection Recovery

Tags: visual-c++, directx, directx-11, c++-amp

I am trying to use C++ AMP to execute a long running kernel on the GPU. This requires using DirectX to create a device which won't timeout. I am setting the flag but it is still triggering Timeout Detection Recovery. I have a dedicated Radeon HD 7970 in my box without a monitor plugged into it. Is there anything else I need to do to keep Windows 8 from canceling my kernel before it is finished?

```
#include <amp.h>
#include <amp_math.h>
#include <amp_graphics.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <dxgi.h>

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "amp_tinymt_rng.h"
#include "timer.h"
#include <assert.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11")
#pragma comment(lib, "dxgi")

//Inside Main()
    unsigned int createDeviceFlags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DISABLE_GPU_TIMEOUT;
    ID3D11Device * pDevice = nullptr;
    ID3D11DeviceContext * pContext = nullptr;
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL targetFeatureLevels = D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1;
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevel;
    auto hr = D3D11CreateDevice(pAdapter, 
                            D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_UNKNOWN, 
                            nullptr, 
                            createDeviceFlags, 
                            &targetFeatureLevels, 
                            1, 
                            D3D11_SDK_VERSION, 
                            &pDevice, 
                            &featureLevel, 
                            &pContext);

    if (FAILED( hr) || 
        ( featureLevel != D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1))
    { 
        std:: wcerr << "Failed to create Direct3D 11 device" << std:: endl; 
        return 10; 
    }

accelerator_view noTimeoutAcclView = concurrency::direct3d::create_accelerator_view(pDevice);
wcout << noTimeoutAcclView.accelerator.description;

//Setup kernal here
concurrency::parallel_for_each(noTimeoutAcclView, e_size, [=] (index<1> idx) restrict(amp) {
   //Execute kernel here
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your snippet looks good, the problem has to be elsewhere. Here are few ideas:

- Please double check all parallel_for_each invocations and make sure
  they all use accelerator_view with the device that you created with
  this snippet (explicitly pass accelerator_view as first argument to parallel_for_each).
- If possible reduce the problem size and see if your code runs without
  TDR, perhaps something else is causing a TDR (e.g. driver bugs are common cause of TDRs). Once you will know that your algorithm runs correctly for smaller problem you can go back to searching why is TDR triggered for larger problem size.
- Disable TDR completely ([see MSDN article on TDR registry keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff569918%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)) and see if your large problem
  set ever completes, if so go back to first point. This will indicate that your code runs on accelerator_view that has TDR enabled.

Good luck!

Comment: Simon, in response to point 2, if I use a smaller instance size it does not cause a TDR. It is only when I scale it up and increase the run length that it causes a TDR. Thank you for the help.

Comment: When I get back I'll put up more code showing the creation of the Accelerator_View and the invocation of the parallel_for_each to make sure I'm doing that correctly as well.

Comment: I added some code to the end which shows the creation of the Accelerator_View and executes the parallel_for_each. Unfortunetly, my Nvidia GTX 550 Ti is not DirectX 11.1 capable. I need to get another AMD graphics card. I'll try to get one in the next couple of days and get back to you.

Comment: I was unsuccessful in programmatically disabling the GPU timeout. I had to go into the Windows registry and disable it there. After I did that everything worked beautifully. For some reason Windows keeps triggering TDR even when I've added the flag to disable GPU timeout.